# Equivalency of two optimization problems

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given functions $f$ and $g$, P1 and P2 below are said to be two equivalent formulations of the support vector machine. How does one show the equivalence?

P1: \begin{align}
\beta^*(\lambda)=\text{argmin}_\beta &\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\big(1-f(\beta;x_i)\big)_++\lambda g(\beta)\right) \\
& g(\beta^*(\lambda))=0
\end{align}
where $\lambda\ge0$ is a constant and $u_+:=\max(0,u)$.

P2: \begin{align}
\max_\beta\ &M \\
&g(\beta) = 0 \\
&f(\beta;x_i) \ge M(1-\epsilon_i) \\
&\epsilon_i\ge0,\ \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i\le C \\
& \forall i
\end{align}
where $C\ge0$ is a parameter.

Obviously $\lambda g(\beta)$ in P1 is the Lagrange multiplier. I do not see immediately how $M$ in P2 emerges from P1.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if P1 enforces $g(\beta)=0$, why include $g(\beta)$ in the objective function? Also, is this claiming that P1 and P2 are equivalent for _any_ functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @DavidM.: You are right. It is not a good formulation. I have edited it. I think the answer to your last question is affirmative, but am not sure. Originally, $f$ is set to a bilinear function of $(\beta, x)$ and $g$ a quadratic function. But I do not see why this restriction is material.